How to add a relation in Typeorm without loading all of them
I have the following entities:
@Entity('user')
class User {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(() => Poll, poll => poll.votedUsers)
    votedPolls!: Poll[]
}

@Entity('poll')
class Poll {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.votedPolls)
    @JoinTable()
    votedUsers!: User[] 
}

Now i want to load a poll, add a new user that voted and store it. There are two problems however:

Its not atomic. If two users vote at the same time, one of them would not be stored as voted (or at least as i understand the way TypeORM works)
I need to load ALL the users with the poll, add one to them, and then store all of them, which is not efficient

I searched the documentation of TypeORM and found nothing. The only thing I found was loading not all users, but all user ids. But Its also not the best way as number of voted users grows

I think you are missing Junction Table scenario:
Documentation: https://typeorm.io/many-to-many-relations

First you create Users
Create Polls
then store entries to junction table that contain userId and PollId


How to load when needed in the code:
For reading just add filter and specify relation that should be loaded. For this you can check select queries in the documentation. https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#joining-relations
